# Is there a internet permission command to be added in the Windows Folder of the Flutter Application for internet usage?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am developing a simple flutter application for my manufacturing facility, where we want to input the stock ids of the raw materials which were used to develop the product. I made a simple Flutter Application with Windows and macOS and Android & IOS enabled while initiating the project in Android Studio. I am using **Mysql1** dependency from pub dev to avoid writing large amounts of backend and use other frameworks.

Furthermore, I also added internet permission for the app in the Androids folder. However, when I was trying to do it on the windows app, the MySQL query would not go through. The MySql server is hosted on Digital Ocean. I entered the exact details,
But works on the android phone and not on windows applications. Do we need to add any same permission line in the Windows Folder?

I installed the application on my physical, it is perfectly sending the data to the MySQL table in the DigitalOcean server. However, doesn't seem to do the same in the windows application. I want it to run the query the same as in the windows desktop app as in the android app.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks and Regards.